# Get SalesFormLetter class from SalesEditLines form formRun using PreHandler AX7

Tags: event-handling, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I need to make some changes on **closeOk** of *SalesEditLines* form. As I know, I am not able to change the standard methods, so I need to create an event handler for closeOk.

```
[PreHandlerFor(formStr(SalesEditLines), formMethodStr(SalesEditLines, closeOk))]
public static void SalesEditLines_Pre_closeOk(XppPrePostArgs args)
{
    FormRun sender  = args.getThis() as FormRun;
    Object callerObject = sender.args().caller();
}
```

The question is - how can i access a **SalesFormLetter** through SalesEditLines form formRun using PreHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the following line in `init` method of `SalesEditLines` form

```
salesFormLetter = element.args().caller();
```

So your `callerObject` is an instance of SalesFormLetter class, you need just cast it to proper type.

Please check the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/expression-operators-is-and-as-for-inheritance